# VBA code for overriding blank looking cells in excel

Tags: excel, vba

There are occasions when we use an `IF` formula, something like this in B1 for example `=IF(A1=1,5000,"")`, and the results seem to be like either 5000 or a blank cells. But the blank cell is not actually blank as it contains a formula which has returned "" - that's why the cell looks blank.

When we drag the formula from B1 to B10 (say), then 10 cells are selected. And then I have written the below code to make the cells which have returned as "" to be empty.

```
Option Explicit
Sub delblanks()
For Each cell In Selection
    If cell.Value = "" Then cell.Value = ""
Next
End Sub
```

...it triggers the error

> variable not defined

How to fix this???

Comment: Because you have `Option Explicit`. You have to declare the `cell` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This here should fix it. `Option Explicit` gives an error when you do not declare your variables.

```
Option Explicit
Sub delblanks()
  Dim cell As Range
  For Each cell In Selection
      If cell.Value = "" Then cell.Value = ""
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Dim cell As Range, Can u explain what u just did. Declaring dim as long, integer is i m familiar with. But what is that you have done.

Comment: [Dim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dim-statement) is what you use to declare a variable. like `Dim variablename As type` variablename in this case is cell, and the type of the variable is a [Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)). A type could also be for example a String or Integer like you said. Range is just a more complex object type. When you enable the `Explicit` option. You have to declare all your variables like that. See the links for a better explaination on what Dim and Range are.

Answer (score -1):

Why not put an actual variable instead of just "" and delete it using your code?

Comment: For this kind of consideration, please use the comments section